# Swift: println value to pass

Tags: swift, types

I am just curious about `println()` method in Swift. I should pass `value: T`. Actually, I can write there: `float`, `string`, `char`, `int`, and even `NSData` for example. How do I create and implement such a type?

EDIT: For those who don't understand what I am asking for: What is `value: T` and how do I use it in my functions?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. `println` is a generic function, and `T` is the placeholder type. What do you want to create or implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` means `println` accepts a parameter of any type.

`float`, `string`, `char`, `int` etc will be converted to a string.

Objects (like `NSData` or `UIImage`) will have their `description` method called, and return that. `NSData` will give you a hexadecimal representation of the data, while `UIImage` prints some details about the image (width, height, etc).

If you want to print out classes you've defined yourself, you should consider implementing a description method. Otherwise you'll just get the class name and memory address.

Also, you can embed an object of any type in a string and combine that with println():

```
let a = 7
let b = 6
let c = a * b

println("\(a) times \(b) is \(c)")
  // 7 times 6 is 42
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that inside that, it just calls `String(value)`.

But if you want to be able to handle many types in your methods, you should check what type it is, and handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example. Suppose `aFloatVar` is a variable of type Float, and you want to write it with appropriate prompt. This is what you have to write:

```
    println("The Value \(aFloatVar as Float)")
```

You may also use two variables in the same line. Suppose `crd` is a CGPoint, and you wish to write it's x and y. Here is what you have to code:

```
    println("Coordinate X = \(crd.x as CGFloat) Y = \(crd.y as CGFloat) ")
```

This is what I know you have to write instead of Value:T in swift.